# Virtualizing Highly Available SQL Server database on SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, database, virtual-machine

I am planning on virtualizing my `SharePoint` environment. So, I am thinking on virtualizing all the roles (Application Server, Frontend, ...) including the Database. 
My question is: is it recommended to virtualize the Database server for the `SharePoint` or not? And if it is, what would be the best way to ensure high availability? Disk mirroring, Availability Groups or something else?

Comment: Hello @Saleh Omar, Your feedback is very important 1. Are the below answers didn't helped you? 2. Do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with these clarifications, else please upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is supported to virtualize the SQL Server, but we cannot make a specific recommendation for you as that would require knowing the performance of the hardware, required overhead, and so on. The best thing you can do is verify the virtualized hardware can support the existing load + some overhead of your SQL instance.

As far as the recommended route, you should be using AlwaysOn Availability Groups with SQL Enterprise. Database Mirroring is a deprecated technology.

Comment: First of all thank you @Trevor Seward. Let's assume that I have a very strong hardware. Is there any technical impedance that may hinder virtualizing SQL Server?

Comment: Not in my opinion or experience.